# How to get id from class

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I want to get the id name from class selector. How can I do it?

```
<div class="tab-pane active popup_RC" id="Basic">
```

at `$(.tab-pane active)` I need its id `Basic`

Comment: should be `.tab-pane.active`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use **[`attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)** method to get an attribute

```
$('.tab-pane.active').attr('id')
```

```js
console.log(
  $('.tab-pane.active').attr('id')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="tab-pane active popup_RC" id="Basic">
```

---

or get `id` property using **[`prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/)** or get it from dom object.

```
$('.tab-pane.active')[0].id
// or
$('.tab-pane.active').prop('id')
```

```js
console.log(
  $('.tab-pane.active')[0].id
);

console.log(
  $('.tab-pane.active').prop('id')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="tab-pane active popup_RC" id="Basic">
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use attribute selector `attr("id")`

```
$('.tab-pane.active').attr("id")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.attr()` to get any attribute of the element

```
$('.tab-pane active').attr('id');
```